# Jenkins Consolidate Email Notifications with all upstream job status in a single mail

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

Is there any way to get build number, build status and build url information of all upstream jobs of a build pipeline at last job.
 I have many jobs connected to each other. A  triggers B, B triggers C.  I do not want to send success email for every project but want to send email on last downstream build. But email should contains links to logs for all upstream builds.

```
The Mail content would like to be as below:

Job A: Build number #1 SUCCESS Console output: <console link>
Job B: Build number #1 FAILED     Console output: <console link>
Job C: Build number #1 SUCCESS Console output: <console link>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Email-ext plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Email-ext+plugin) for sending emails. The advantage of this plugin is we can write our own mail templates using groovy.

You can find some examples [here](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Email-ext+Recipes) and also some more examples from plugin [source](https://github.com/jenkinsci/email-ext-plugin/tree/master/src/main/resources/hudson/plugins/emailext/templates) itself.